# Electromagnetic field tensor and antisymmetry

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity, classical-electrodynamics

Why does the inner product between the four force (caused by the electromagnetic field tensor) and the four velocity equaling zero imply that the electromagnetic field tensor is antisymmetric?[image]
This image is from the textbook General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists by Hobson, Efstathiou and Lasenby

Comment: Please describe where you found this claim and include the formulas that you are referring to. You can use latex formatting.

Comment: @my2cts Oh sorry, I don’t really know how to use latex. I found this claim in General Relativity: An Introduction to Physicists by M. P. Hobson, G. Efstathiou and A. N. Lasenby on page 136.

Comment: $F_{mn}u^m u^n = 0, \; F_{nm}u^n u^m = 0$. Add the two expressions and use the fact that $u^m u^n$ is symmetric $\implies (F_{mn} + F_{nm})u^m u^n = 0 \implies F_{mn} = -F_{nm}$. In general, the product of a symmetric and antisymmetric tensor is zero.

Comment: Perhaps you can update the question now, using all this information.

Comment: And the question remains if the reasoning is circular.

Comment: @GodotMisogi you have only shown that product of two symmetric matrices $(F_{mn}+F_{nm})$ and $u^mu^n$ has zero trace. Is this sufficient to conclude one of them is zero matrix?

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks, I was mistaken. It was bugging me how the textbook directly concludes this, but my sleep-deprivation misled me into thinking it's that direct.

Comment: @GodotMisogi It is bugging me as well. I also think the usual argument from the equation of motion cannot work without some other ideas because $u^m$'s are not independent of each other.

Comment: Why would $F_{m'n} u^mu^n$ zero, if the antisymmetry of F is not a given?

Comment: $a_{\mu}u^{\mu}$ is given, with substitution of the equation of motion.

Answer (score 4):

The premise is that $F_{ab}u^a u^b=0$ for all timelike $u$. I'll abbreviate this as $uFu=0$.

Given any two timelike vectors $x$ and $y$, we can multiply one of them by a non-zero scale factor so that $x+y$ is also timelike. Then the premise implies
$$
xFx=0
\hskip2cm
yFy=0
\hskip2cm
(x+y)F(x+y)=0.
\tag{1}
$$
This combination of equations implies
$$
xFy+yFx=0.
\tag{2}
$$
Since $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary timelike vectors except for the relative scale factor, and since the relative scale vector doesn't affect equation (2), equation (2) holds for any two timelike vectors.

Any spacelike or lightlike vector $x'$ can be written as the difference of two non-zero timelike vectors, and likewise for any spacelike or lightlike vector $y'$, so equation (2) implies $x'Fy'+y'Fx'=0$ for all vectors $x'$ and $y'$. Since this is true in particular for all of the vectors in some orthogonal basis, this immediately implies that $F$ is antisymmetric.